# How save a load rich text from mysql using winforms

Tags: c#, mysql, winforms, richtextbox

I'm trying to save and load richtext using a mysql db and winfoms.

What is the datatype I have to use in mysql and how load the text in richtextbox?

Actually I'm using `VARCHAR(5000)` as the datatype and load the richtextbox like this

```cs
rtbannotations.Text = meetings.annotations;
```

But the text appears unformatted.

Comment: `rtbannotations.RTF = [some RTF from DB]`. Note: you also need to store the RTF, not the text (i.e., `rtbannotations.RTF`) into that field in the database.

Comment: Varchar is fine, just use the RTF property, which contains the formatted text.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming you have methods to store richTextFormat in your database and to fetch it:

```
void StoreRichText(..., string richText);
string FetchRichText(...);
```

To store the contents of a RichTextBox:

```
void StoreRichText(RichTextBox rtb, ...)
{
    string richText = rtb.Rtf;
    StoreRichText(..., richText);
}

void ShowRichText(RichTextbox rtb, ...)
{
    string richText = FetchRichtext(...);
    rtb.Rtf = richText;
}
```

Simple comme bonjour!